# HTML and Django

Tags: html, django

urls.py contains the line:

```
url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),
```

views.py contains the code:

```
def topics(request):
    context = locals()
    return render(request, 'topics.html', context)
```

The following bootstrap code is used to open "topics.html"

```
<p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="/topics/" role="button">More &raquo;</a></p>
```

The above code renders "topics.html" correctly  which is a table.

Now, I want the cursor to go to a specific row( Ex: first row) in the table.

Comment: Could you re-phrase the actual question again ? I'm a little confused what you mean by `I want the cursor to go to a specific row( Ex: first row) in the table.` Maybe you want the page to jump to a section on load ?

Comment: do you mean that on a certain row there is an input element that you want to start in? what have you researched/tried?

Comment: never ever use `context = locals()`!

Comment: Hi Pogrindis: I want the first row to be selected/highlighted.

Comment: @Sayse: I tried with <section id="aaa" > to make it jump to the desired location . I used "/topics/#aaa". But it did not help. I want  a specific row to be selected/highlighted. Thanks for your help. Billz

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear for me what cursor you mean, but may be you can assign a unique id to each row like
 `<tr id="row-1"><tr id="row-2"><tr id="row-3"><tr id="row-4">`
then you can jump to that id using

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="/topics/#row-1" role="button"></a> 
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="/topics/#row-2" role="button"></a> 
...
```

it may look a little bit basic, but with the few clues you set i think it could be a start...

Comment: Hi Carlos:                                                                                                        Sorry, I was not clear enough. I want the first row to be selected/highlighted. I tried your suggestion. It does not seem to help. Atleast, I would like to have the first element in the first row to be selected/highlighted.                                                                                              Thanks for your help. Billz

Comment: Hi Billz: jumping to an #id will scroll the html document so it's visible. What is not easy to understand is what do you mean with "selected" or "highlited". In my code that usually means that a given element has an "hilite" class or sth like that, but in your case i can tell.

Comment: Hi Carlos: Yes. I meant having a css class “hilite” when I open up that page.
I was able to accomplish it  last night as follows:
<tr id = {{row}} {%  if '/topics/1'  in request.path  %}   style="background-color:#FFFFAA" {% endif %} </tr>
That did the trick. I have to perfect my code. Once I do that, I will send it out.
Thanks for putting me on the right track.
Appreciate your help.
Regards,
Billz.